# Save the settings regarding the appearance of the task manager windows server 2012 r2

Tags: task-manager, windows-server-2012-r2

On windows server 2012r2, I like to configure my task manager to show things like the command line, but sometimes, after a reboot (due to a crash or not), my task manager is reset to the usual display, here for the performance panel

[image]

How do I save and restore my personal settings after a crash?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10, this works:
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7030-task-manager-settings-backup-restore.html 
I'll bet it works similarly in Server 2012.